# Подключить ко всем html страницам Общие библиотеки

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Имеется файл index.html
 В нем я загружаю это меню:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#menu').load('page/menu.html');
    });
</script>


<div id="menu"></div>
```

Дальше я хочу подключить по нажатию

```
   <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="">Обо мне</a>
   </li>
```

новую html страницу с сохранением меню и не плодить однотипный код.

Я хотел заменить на ссылку на кнопки и через js загружать страницу как меню в div,будет ли это правильной логикой работы. Что бы не подключать в каждом файле новые библиотеки.

Comment: Вы строите сайт только на HTML/JavaScript? PHP/JSP/JSF совсем не используете?

Comment: Испольщывать буду Mean.js

Comment: И что там разве нет какого-нибудь `<% include(...)%>`?

Comment: Я новичек, не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [templates](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates)

```
<header>

  {{logo}}

  <span>+380987654321</span>

  {{navigation}}

</header>
```